# Carrousel, con botón siguiente y atrás

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenas tengo un carrousel con dos `div` y he añadido dos botones `<` `>` para poder cambiar una con la otra. Pero no consigo que me funcione correctamente, la posición se queda mal.

```js
var proceso;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var actualIndice = 0;
  var objetos = $('.contenedor > div');
  var numObjetos = objetos.length;

  function cambiarImagen() {
    var imagen = objetos.eq(actualIndice);
    objetos.hide();
    imagen.css('display', 'block');
  }
  //proceso = setInterval(function() {
  //  actualIndice += 1;
  //  if (actualIndice > (numObjetos - 1)) {
  //    actualIndice = 0;
  //  }
  //  cambiarImagen();
  //}, 3000);
  $('.siguiente').click(function() {
    limpiarIntervalo();
    actualIndice += 1;
    if (actualIndice > (numObjetos - 1)) {
      actualIndice = 0;
    }
    cambiarImagen();
  });
  $('.anterior').click(function() {
    limpiarIntervalo();
    actualIndice -= 1;
    if (actualIndice < 0) {
      actualIndice = numObjetos - 1;
    }
    cambiarImagen();
  });
});

function limpiarIntervalo() {
  window.clearInterval(proceso);
}
```

```css
.cardsTwo {
  background: #9124a4;
  position: absolute;
  top: -114%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.padCardsTwo {
  padding: 43px 25px;
}

.cardsTwo h3 {
  font-size: 2.9rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
}

.cardsTwo h4 {
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #ffeb3b;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}

.cardsTwo p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 16%;
}

.btnResDiVer {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background: #00ce80;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 11px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #00ce80;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: block;
}

.btnResDiVer2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 11px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: block;
  border: solid 2px #eeafe1;
}

.anterior {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 206px;
  left: 40px;
}

.siguiente {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 206px;
  left: 854px;
}

.cardsTwo2 {
  background: #02cd80;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  left: 179px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 515px;
}

.btnResDiVer2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 11px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: block;
  border: solid 2px #eeafe1;
}

.btnResDiVer {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background: #00ce80;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 11px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #00ce80;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="contenedor">
  <div>
    <div class="cardsTwo2">
      <div class="padCardsTwo">
        <h3>Láser de diodo</h3>
        <h4>Desde 10€</h4>
        <p>Depilate con nuestro láser de diodo<br>sin bonos ni ataduras<br>¡Así de fácil!</p>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer">Reserva tu cita</a>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer2">Ver nuestras tarifas</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="col-9 offset-md-2 cardsTwo">
      <div class="padCardsTwo">
        <h3>Láser de diodo</h3>
        <h4>Desde 10€</h4>
        <p>Depilate con nuestro láser de diodo<br>sin bonos ni ataduras<br>¡Así de fácil!</p>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer">Reserva tu cita</a>
        <a href="" class="btnResDiVer2">Ver nuestras tarifas</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="anterior">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
</div>
<div class="siguiente">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alguna sugerencia @Jheyman Mejia

Comment: Creo que estás reinventando la rueda, y si ajustas lo que tienes usando el carrousel de Bootstrap? Lo único que estás usando propiamente y distinto a lo que te ofrece BS es el CSS, que por cierto te quedó muy bien

Comment: gracias @JheymanMejia , no se como puedo ajustarlo con el de BS, puedes ayudarme?? gracias por la edición del mensaje ;)